# Bootstrap 4 Form Input - Align checkboxes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap Form that uses checkboxes - in one case there are a large number of options to choose from. Is it possible to align these so they appear in 'columns' or similar - at the moment they just appear in one long list which makes it hard to read.

Here's how it currently looks:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <main role="main" class="container">

    <div>

      <form method="get" action="projects.php" role="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="projectsFind">

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="sectionNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Section Number</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sectionNumber" name="sectionNumber" placeholder="Section Number">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">Selections</div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Hot Food">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Hot Food            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Retail">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Retail            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Affordable">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Affordable            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Canteen">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Canteen            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="At Home">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            At Home            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Residential">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Residential            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Hospitality">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Hospitality            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Supermarket">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Supermarket            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Education">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Education            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Student">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Student            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Leisure">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Leisure            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Exhibition">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Exhibition            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Health">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Health            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Seniors">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Seniors            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Restaurant">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Restaurant            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Standard">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Standard            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Industry">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Industry            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Social">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Social            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Recycle">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Recycle            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Re-use">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Re-use            </label>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>



      </form>
```

You can see the "Selections" are just listed in a running list. Is there a way to make the "Selections" checkboxes aligned in a more easy to read format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add fixed width to the `.form-check-inline`.This will align them in a column like layout.

The value of the width should be little more than the width of the longest word.

```css
.form-check-inline {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <main role="main" class="container">

    <div>

      <form method="get" action="projects.php" role="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="projectsFind">

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="sectionNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Section Number</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sectionNumber" name="sectionNumber" placeholder="Section Number">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">Selections</div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Hot Food">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Hot Food            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Retail">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Retail            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Affordable">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Affordable            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Canteen">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Canteen            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="At Home">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            At Home            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Residential">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Residential            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Hospitality">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Hospitality            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Supermarket">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Supermarket            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Education">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Education            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Student">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Student            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Leisure">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Leisure            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Exhibition">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Exhibition            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Health">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Health            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Seniors">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Seniors            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Restaurant">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Restaurant            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Standard">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Standard            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Industry">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Industry            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Social">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Social            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Recycle">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Recycle            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="footTypes[]" id="footTypes" value="Re-use">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Re-use            </label>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>



      </form>
```